# why when I add "else" after an "if" statement the code doesn't function correctly?

Tags: c, loops, if-statement, while-loop, do-while

I'm writing code that takes any number from the user, it tells the user if the input contains 3,6, or 9. else, the code should print out the same input. 
I managed to get the "if" correctly, if the user input any number, the code will tell if it contained 3, 6, or 9.
However, when I add the "else" part, the code doesn't work anymore, and it wont tell if the inserted number contained 3, 6, or 9.

This code can detect any number:

```
int i;

    printf("Enter a number:");
    scanf_s("%d", &i);
    int L = i;
    int n = 0;

    while (i > 0)
    {
        n = i % 10;
        i = i / 10;
        if (n == 3 || n == 6 || n == 9)
        {
            printf("There is a 3 or 6 or 9.");
            break;
        }
```

adding these lines to the above code wont make it work correctly

```
else
        {
            printf("%d", L);
            break;
        }
```

input: 300

output without else statement:"There is a 3 or 6 or 9." 
(Correct)

output with else statement: 300
(incorrect)

why is that?

Comment: Because your `if` is inside `while` loop and the first iteration will gives `n==0`. Review your logic again.

Comment: You probably don't want the `break` in the else; you want to continue on to the next digit (iteration of the loop).  As it stands, you don't actually loop; you always break on the first iteration.

Comment: Please show us the entire code snippet so we can reproduce your error. Right now,  your `while` loop doesn't have a closing `}`, and your indentation implies that maybe this was supposed to be in a function? maybe not? `int i;` is left aligned while the rest is indented in?

Comment: If you enter 300, consider the first loop iteration.  `n` is 300 % 10 which is 0.  Is `n` 3 or 6 or 9?  Nope.  So you enter your `else`, print 300, and break from the loop.  It's doing exactly what you told it to do.  You shouldn't give up until you've checked *all* the digits.  Just keep track of whether you've seen a 3 or 6 or 9, and then *after* the loop, if you haven't seen any, *then* print your fail message.

Comment: Hello, Wawa! A hint is to keep the else part outside the loop and use a flag variable to track if your if the condition gets called. If the if condition is true(check using the flag) break and don't print the actual number, otherwise print it.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite the loop the following way

```
do
{
    n = i % 10;
    if (n == 3 || n == 6 || n == 9)
    {
        printf("There is a 3 or 6 or 9.");
        break;
    }

} while (  i /= 10 );

if ( i == 0 )   printf("%d", L);
```

Otherwise if a next digit (for example 0) of the number is not equal to 3, 6, or 9 the else statement is executed and there is exit from the loop.